# Do Alertness and Dark Blue Rhomboïd stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats

Let's assume someone gets the [Alertness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/alertness---final) feat and a [Dark Blue Rhomboïd Ioun Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/dark-blue-rhomboid-ioun-stone) turning upon his head. Do the bonuses from both stack, to make +4 (+8 if 10 ranks) to Perception/Sense Motive checks or does this count as "twice the same source"?

If they don't stack, does the cracked version of the ioun stone stack with the feat?

Answer (score 6):

The *Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Core Rules* says, "If a character has the same feat more than once, its benefits do not stack unless indicated otherwise in the description" (113). The feat [Alertness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/alertness---final) does *not* indicate otherwise, so a creature already possessing the feat Alertness that sends spinning an [*ioun stone* (dark blue rhomboid)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/dark-blue-rhomboid-ioun-stone) actually *has* the effect of the feat Alertness *twice* but the benefits of the feat Alertness only *once*.

The competence bonus granted by *either* the *ioun stone* (cracked dark blue rhomboid) *or* the *ioun stone* (flawed dark blue rhomboid) *does* stack with the feat Alertness, but the two competence bonuses from both those *ioun stones* don't stack with each other because the bonuses have the same name—use instead only the highest competence bonus.

Comment: From where do you see the dark blue rhomboid give a *competence* bonus ? I can't find it.

Comment: @AnneAunyme While the typical *stone* grants the feat Alertness, the cracked and flawed *stones* each grant a competence bonus instead.

Comment: Are you really sure granting "the effects of the Alertness feat" is the same as "granting the Alertness feat"?

Comment: @AnneAunyme Nope. I had made a technical error and later corrected it (that's the edit I made where it says *edited XX hours ago*). Although gaining a feat's effect *is* a lot like gaining the feat, technically gaining the effect of a feat is *not* gaining the feat. But, since *actually* having a feat  also *means* also having that feat's effect, having *both* the feat  proper and the same feat's effect separately *is*, often, just as pointless.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr - Alertness does not stack with the dark blue rhomboid stone, but does stack with the cracked version.

### How Bonuses Stack

> The important aspect of bonus types is that two bonuses of the same type don't generally stack... Bonuses without a type always stack, unless they are from the same source.

Source: [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus)

### Dark Blue Rhomboid Ioun Stone: No

The stone grants the user the Alertness feat. It does not stack with the Alertness feat, because these are both from the same source (Alertness).

### Cracked Ioun Stone: Yes

The cracked version of the stone does not grant Alertness, it grants a competence bonus. Alertness may stack with this bonus because they come from two different sources. The key here is that the types of the bonuses need to be different. Because the bonuses are of different types, they stack.

Comment: Technically the ioun stone don't grand the feat, it grants "the effects of the feat". Are they still the same source ?

Comment: Yes. Having the feat and having the effects of the feat only differ in that the "effects" version doesn't satisfy prereqs for other feats.

Comment: @GreySage That would be a *really* useful thing to cite.